# How to accept only essential security updates?

Tags: updates, security

sometimes i am getting problem in software updates. So i would like to get only essential security updates and also need to make it as default. Please let me know is there any way to sort out that?

Comment: Not sure why my question needed editing: I thought it was OK.

Answer (score 0):

All security updates are essential. Otherwise they would not be "security"updates.

See software&updates for the options you have:

[image]

- The top checkbox is about "important security updates" so keep that one active. If that is all you need uncheck the other 3.
- The 1st 2 dropdown boxes let you set when these are checked and what is done when there is an update (display, download or download+install).

Comment: Hmm - in the grey suggestions text here it says "avoid comments like thanks". But as I do not have points to upvote the answer I am going to say thanks anyway, even though I do not agree that all security updates are essential. I have changed my settings so that only "important security updates" is ticked. As a supplementary question I wonder why "Unsupported updates" is ticked by default?

Comment: Those are updates from backports. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/956405/comments/4 for why this is active (there is no harm in either setting)